# Is it possible for MVVM light ViewModelLocator generate the viewmodel dynamically based on view

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

Is it possible for MVVM light ViewModelLocator identify which view is loading and then generate the viewmodel dynamically?

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    //Find the current window/ user control loading
    ContentControl control = 

    //Generate the View model dynamically

    //Register to dynamically created view model
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SelectedViewModel>();

}
```

[image: My Project structure is given below]

Comment: don't know but that's a great idea!  Auto Generate viewmodels?

Comment: Yes John, so that I don't have to register all different viewmodels in future, so that for next view I can add just view and viewmodel, then all can happen without any code change in the locator.

Comment: Whyt not just create a new ViewModel then pass the VM to the View constructor and create it in code. It isn't much more code and is more obvious what you are doing.

Comment: @rolls, that way I have to do a lot of coding. MVVM-Light MVL is reducing the coding a lot. The only problem I saw was for each time when I add a new view, me (someone in my team) has to add a property variable to VML to handle it, so I asked this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid ViewModelLocator coding switch to a naming convention based framework like MVVMCross. In MVVMCross you don't have a locator at all, simply create a MyViewModel object and a MyView view: the framework matches them based on name convention.

Comment: I like it, but that would take away benefits I get in MVVM light.